# Naming variables with "my" to show they're not a part of a library?

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions

I'm writing helper functions to simplify my use of an existing library. In this particular case, just for examples sake, I'm writing a helper function to get a doc from firestore. I've always named my helper functions things like `getMyDoc()` to clarify that it's my own way to get a doc and not a part of the standard library, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791730/why-do-people-put-my-in-their-variable-names) this is bad practice. Naming it `getDocHelper()` sounds funny to me. What should I be doing?

EDIT (@Alex Wayne):
Added example code below. Really all this code does is eliminates boilerplate for the `docRef.get()` call, which gets a document from the database. There's really nothing special about it - most of it is taken directly from the [docs themselves](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). I don't want to use the same name as from the library because this would get real confusing trying to read, I'd always be having to look at which import I used. I guess I could call it like `docGetSimplified()`, since it's simplifying the code, but like... idk maybe that's it then? `firestoreDocGetSimplified()`?

```
const getMyFirestoreData = async (collectionId: string, documentId: string): Promise<DocumentData> => {
    const db = admin.firestore()
    const docRef = db.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId);
    const doc = await docRef.get()
    if (!doc.exists) {
        functions.logger.error(`Doc doesn't exist with collectionId ${collectionId} and documentId ${documentId}`)
        throw new Error(`Doc doesn't exist with collectionId ${collectionId} and documentId ${documentId}`)
    } else {
        const docData = doc.data();
        if (docData === undefined) {
            functions.logger.error(`Doc exists but data() is undefined with collectionId ${collectionId} and documentId ${documentId}`)
            throw new Error(`Doc exists but data() is undefined with collectionId ${collectionId} and documentId ${documentId}`)
        } else {
            return docData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can tell where a function comes from by where you import it from. But it's hard to give highly general naming advice. What does `getMyDoc` in this case actually do? What does it do that `getDoc` from the library does not? Whatever it does, should likely be part of the name. Or just use the same name but import from your own file all the time. Please [edit] your question with some example and I bet we can get some better names for those cases.

Comment: Why not just name the function `getDocumentData` or even shorter, `documentData` (you probably don't need to expose the name Firebase). These names will not clash with any identifiers in the library, right?